# Android TTS different languages supported each time when checked

Tags: android

I am struggling with one very strange bug in my app.

I have added TTS to it, and I am using the build one. The user can choose the language from the spinner which is filled in during `AsyncTask` started in `onResume()`.

The `AsyncTask` looks like this:

```
private class AsyncTTSDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                languagesTTS = tts.testLang();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (D)
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ttsUpdate.dismiss();

            TTSSpinnerAdapter adapterTTS = new TTSSpinnerAdapter(
                    MyTTS.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    languagesTTS);

            int savedLangTTS = ttsLang.getInt("savedTTS", -1);

            langTTS.setAdapter(adapterTTS);
            if (savedLangTTS == -1)
            {
                try {
                    int langObject = languagesTTS.indexOf(tts.getLanguage());
                    langTTS.setSelection(langObject);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie) {
                    langTTS.setSelection(0);
                }
            } else {
                langTTS.setSelection(savedLangTTS);
            }
            Locale langChoosen = (Locale) langTTS.getItemAtPosition(langTTS
                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
            tts.setTTSLanguage(langChoosen);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ttsUpdate = ProgressDialog.show(MyTTS.this, "Wait",
                    "Loading TTS...");
            ttsUpdate.setCancelable(false);
        }
    }
```

the thing is, that I am from time to time getting different number of languages supported. **This is on this same device, during this same run**. Just I open and close Activity with TTS. This bug is causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is my way of getting TTS languages:

```
public List<Locale> testLang() {
        Locale[] AvalLoc = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        List<Locale> listaOK = new ArrayList<Locale>();
        String tester = "";

        for (Locale l : AvalLoc) {
            if(tester.contains(l.getLanguage()))
            {
                continue;
            }
            int buf = tts.isLanguageAvailable(l);
            if (buf == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || buf == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                //TODO maybe
            } else {
                listaOK.add(l);
                tester += l.getLanguage() + ";";
            }
        }
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return listaOK;
    }
```

For now I've only find out a small hack for not showing this error, just save in shared preferences number of languages and compare it with what tts received, but it is not working well at all. Each time I am getting different number.

For me it seems, that something is not finished or started when I am starting again this same activity after return, because this is `tts.isAvaliableLanguage(l)` who is deciding whether language is supported or not and from time to time, one language is not supported and after reload it is.

**EDIT:**

As there appeared new comment about my question I need to add one important thing about TTS engine itself.

`testLang()` is a method inside my class Called `TTSClass`, that is implementing `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`. tts object is created in onCreate of `MyTTS` activity and this constructor looks like this in `TTSClass`:

```
public TTSClass(Context context, Locale language) {
        contextTTS = context;
        languageTTS = language;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(contextTTS, this);
    }
```

and call in activity:

```
tts = new TTSClass(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Because `TTSClass` implements `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` there is also `onInit()` method which looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = 0;

            result = tts.setLanguage(languageTTS);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "This Language is not supported");
            }
            if(D) Log.d(TAG,"Initialized");

        } else {
            if(D) Log.e(TAG, "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }
```

So, this is everything connecting to this class and problem I think. If anything is missing, let me now.

**EDIT2:**

Suggested by shoe rat comment I've run few more tests, and the outcome is just amazing, or extraordinary, I think it is better word.

So what I've done was adding 3 `Log` from different places in code informing me about list size on different stages.

First was added in `onInit()` in if `status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`. This one is just simple call of `testLang().size()`. The outcome is 5 languages - that is the correct number and it is always like this, no matter if there is or isn't an exception.

Second was added there:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.w(TAG,"before: "+tts.testLang().size());
                languagesTTS = tts.testLang();
            }
```

and this one is starting to act quite weird. It is sometimes, or even quite often, showing number lower than 5. But this is not the strangest thing.

The third one is just at the beginning of `onPostExecute` checking the size of languagesTTS. And believe or not, the number is quite often totally different from the second log. However, it is never smaller. It can be equal or bigger.

Does anyone know, what is going one?

Comment: Sounds like a TTS engine initialization related issue: you need to call `isLanguageAvailable()` only after the [engine initialization has completed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.html#onInit(int))

Comment: it is initialized, I've checked it. Also I'm getting in LogCat info, from TTS itself, that he has been initialize. I think this is something else.

Comment: How did you do the check?

Comment: I've edited my code, feel free to check.

Comment: Cool. Call `testLang()` from `onInit()` and if only `status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`, and see what happens.

Comment: done, check the outcome, you will be amused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. It came out that indeed it was initialization problem.

I'm not sure if documentation is saying anything about it, but it seem like the **TTS engine initialization is done asynchronously**, so it can finish at any time.

My solution was to change the `doInBackground()` method like this:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                while(!TTSClass.isInit){}
                languagesTTS = tts.testLang();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (D)
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and in `onInit()` method I've added isInit public static boolean variable:

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = 0;

            result = tts.setLanguage(languageTTS);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "This Language is not supported");
            }
            if(D) Log.d(TAG,"initialized");
            isInit = true;


        } else {
            if(D) Log.e(TAG, "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }
```

Hope, that someone will find it helpful.